# Netflix-like hover effect with buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image: Netflix hover effect]

How do I create a hover effect as shown in the gif? All I could do now is zoom it on hover. How do I add the buttons and other details too, on hover?

I've done this so far:

```css
.Row_poster:hover { 
   transform: scale(1.3);
   overflow: visible;
   cursor: pointer;
   z-index: 98;
}
```

Comment: Show your tried code.

Comment: You should update your question with the code under an "update" header and notify in comments that updates were made. Makes it easier to understand your problem as a whole.

Comment: If you need to show buttons on mouseover, then you simply make those buttons invisible by default, and when you find the mouse cursor, you make the buttons visible. A superficial example is `.button {display: none}` and `selector:hover .button {display: block}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pure CSS Methods

Although the effect can be obtained using JavaScript, here are some pure CSS methods.

### Method 1: Use `::after` and `::before`.

Read:

- [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) on MDN
- [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) on MDN

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #141414;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Lato, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.square {
  background-size: cover!important;
  background-position: center!important;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: transform 100ms ease-out, border-radius 200ms ease-out;
}

.square:hover {
  background: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/lgcUUCXgC8mEo/giphy.gif), url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Arrestbygningen_ved_r%C3%A5d-_og_domhuset.jpg/320px-Arrestbygningen_ved_r%C3%A5d-_og_domhuset.jpg), skyblue;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000a;
}

.square::after {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: #18181818;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000a;
  color: #fff;
  width: 150px;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-out, border-radius 200ms ease-out;
}

.square:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.square.one {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Arrestbygningen_ved_r%C3%A5d-_og_domhuset.jpg/320px-Arrestbygningen_ved_r%C3%A5d-_og_domhuset.jpg), skyblue;
}

.square.one:hover {
  background: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/lgcUUCXgC8mEo/giphy.gif), url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Arrestbygningen_ved_r%C3%A5d-_og_domhuset.jpg/320px-Arrestbygningen_ved_r%C3%A5d-_og_domhuset.jpg), skyblue;
}

.square.one::after {
  content: 'Never Gonna Give You Up!';
}
```

```html
<div class="square one"></div>
```

You should prefer using this method if your caption-thing is not very customized.

### Method 2: Use separate `elements`

This method is best no matter how customized is your caption-thing.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #111;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Lato, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.square {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: transform 100ms ease-out, border-radius 200ms ease-out;
}

.square .cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  background-size: cover!important;
  background-position: center!important;
}

.square .text {
  display: none;
  background: #181818;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-out, border-radius 200ms ease-out;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.square:hover {
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000a;
}

.square:hover .text {
  display: block;
}

.square.one .cover {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Arrestbygningen_ved_r%C3%A5d-_og_domhuset.jpg/320px-Arrestbygningen_ved_r%C3%A5d-_og_domhuset.jpg), skyblue;
}

.square.one:hover .cover {
  background: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/lgcUUCXgC8mEo/giphy.gif), url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Arrestbygningen_ved_r%C3%A5d-_og_domhuset.jpg/320px-Arrestbygningen_ved_r%C3%A5d-_og_domhuset.jpg), skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="square one">
  <div class="cover"></div>
  <div class="text">
    Never Gonna Give You Up!
  </div>
</div>
```

### The Result

Use Method 2. This looks very similar to the gif.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #141414;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.square {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: transform 100ms ease-out, border-radius 200ms ease-out;
}

.square .cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  background-size: cover!important;
  background-position: center!important;
}

.square .text {
  display: none;
  background: #181818;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-out, border-radius 200ms ease-out;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.square:hover {
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000a;
}

.square:hover .text {
  display: block;
}

.square.one .cover {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Arrestbygningen_ved_r%C3%A5d-_og_domhuset.jpg/320px-Arrestbygningen_ved_r%C3%A5d-_og_domhuset.jpg), skyblue;
}

.square.one:hover .cover {
  background: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/lgcUUCXgC8mEo/giphy.gif), url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Arrestbygningen_ved_r%C3%A5d-_og_domhuset.jpg/320px-Arrestbygningen_ved_r%C3%A5d-_og_domhuset.jpg), skyblue;
}

.square .text .info {
  font-size: 8px;
}

.icons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.icons :nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.icons span{
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 1000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rating {
  border: 0.1px solid white;
  padding: 1px 2px;
  
}
.match {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="square one">
  <div class="cover"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="icons">
      <span>:)</span>
      <span>O</span>
      <span>V</span>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <span class="match">98% Match</span>
      <span class="rating">18+</span>
      <span class="seasons">5 Seasons</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The second approach I used was successful. However, I want to use it in a slider, and doing so will cause the card to interrupt any other cards and the bottom slider as well ?

Comment: @sohaib Since this effect is achieved with the `transform` property, this will not affect any other cards' positioning. I would recommend adding a `z-index: 999999` to bring the hovered element above all other elements.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Harsh,**

Please have a look at the below code I put together to see if this is what you are trying to achieve, pal.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on('mouseenter', '.transformar', function () {
                    $(this).find(".playButtons").show('slow');
                }).on('mouseleave', '.transformar', function () {
                    $(this).find(".playButtons").hide();
                });
            });
```

```css
.transformar {
display:block;
height:150px;
transition: transform 2s;
}

.playButtons{display: none}

.transformar:hover{
transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='transformar' align="center">

<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e1/d0/1b/e1d01b1b7f602d223afc747fcbced364.jpg" height="150" alt="Netflix Example">
<h2>Filme do Netflix</h2>
<div id="#botones" class="playButtons">
<button type="button">PLAY EPISODE</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: scaling it up isnt the problem. i want the grey part ( all the buttons and text ) to be shown once hovered.

Comment: Please try the code again, Harsh, I made an small adjustment after reading details on your comment. Please click on the Full Page link to see the effect take place. Cheers!

Comment: I did not catch what happened exactly I am kind of new to Stack O, however all I was trying to do is helping another one like I would like to be helped when I need an answer, Jeet please guide me into this matter to find a just solution to it. THanks!